# Explain FB Prophet plot_components

Tags: components, facebook-prophet

I plot the components of FB Prophet model forecast, but I do not know how to well explain the plots.It output "trend","holidays","weekly" and "extra_regressors_multiplicative" line charts.

What do those figures indicate? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

They are all one of the components of the additive (or multiplicative) model (y(t) = g(t) + s(t) + h(t) + ϵₜ) which is Prophet :

- g(t) models trend
- s(t) models seasonality
- h(t) models the effects of holidays or large events
- ϵₜ is the error term

You can think of the seasonality as, for each day, the change from what y would be if there were no seasonality at all.

For instance if the effect of a certain holiday (like Christmas) is +20 (units), it means y(t) would have been 20 units less if it wasn't Christmas.